# WooCommerce editable custom checkout field and displayed in formatted address

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

I am adding mandatory shipping phone to woocommerce checkout page with

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_shipping_phone_to_checkout_page' );

function add_shipping_phone_to_checkout_page( $fields ) {
   $fields['shipping']['shipping_phone'] = array(
      'label' => 'Phone',
      'required' => true,
      'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
      'priority' => 25,
   );
   return $fields;
}
```

then display it in admin order panel

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'shipping_phone_checkout_display_in_order_panel' );

function shipping_phone_checkout_display_in_order_panel( $order ){
    echo '<p><b>Phone :</b> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_shipping_phone', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

and finally print it in email

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details','shipping_phone_display_in_order_email', 25, 4 );

function shipping_phone_display_in_order_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    $output = '';
    $shipping_phone = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_shipping_phone', true );

    if ( !empty($shipping_phone) )
        $output = '<p><strong>' . __( "Phone:", "woocommerce" ) . '</strong> ' . $shipping_phone . '</p>';

    echo $output;

 }
```

All works as it should. I'd like to achieve 2 enhancements but I am unable to do:

1. Make the custom phone field editable in admin panel
2. In email, move the custom phone field value in shipping address block

Any help would be appreciated

[image: woocoomerce email order]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make some changes in your code… The following code will display the shipping phone field in:

- Checkout
- My Account > Address > Edit shipping address
- Admin order edit pages

The code will also add the shipping phone to formatted **displayed** shipping address on emails shipping address section.

```
// display shipping phone in checkout and my account edit shipping address
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'add_shipping_phone_field' );
function add_shipping_phone_field( $fields ) {
   $fields['shipping_phone'] = array(
      'label' => __('Phone (Shipping)'),
      'required' => true,
      'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
      'priority' => 25,
   );
   return $fields;
}

// Editable field on admin order edit pages inside edit shipping section
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields' , 'add_order_admin_edit_shipping_phone' );
function add_order_admin_edit_shipping_phone( $fields ) {
    // Include shipping phone as editable field
    $fields['phone'] = array( 'label' => __("Shipping phone"), 'show' => '0' );

    return $fields;
}

// Adding custom placeholder to woocommerce formatted address only on Backend
add_filter( 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', 'admin_localisation_address_formats', 50, 1 );
function admin_localisation_address_formats( $address_formats ){
    // Only in backend (Admin)
    if( is_admin() || ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        foreach( $address_formats as $country_code => $address_format ) {
            $address_formats[$country_code] .= "\n{phone}";
        }
    }
    return $address_formats;
}

// Custom placeholder replacement to woocommerce formatted address
add_filter( 'woocommerce_formatted_address_replacements', 'custom_formatted_address_replacements', 10, 2 );
function custom_formatted_address_replacements( $replacements, $args  ) {
    $replacements['{phone}'] = ! empty($args['phone']) ? $args['phone'] : '';

    return $replacements;
}

// Add the shipping phone value to be displayed on email notifications under shipping address
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address', 'add_shipping_phone_to_formatted_shipping_address', 100, 2 );
function add_shipping_phone_to_formatted_shipping_address( $shipping_address, $order ) {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    // Not on admin order edit pages (as it's already displayed).
    if( ! ( $pagenow === 'post.php' && $post_type === 'shop_order' && isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'edit' ) ) {
        // Include shipping phone on formatted shipping address
        $shipping_address['phone'] = $order->get_meta('_shipping_phone');
    }
    return $shipping_address;
}

// Remove double billing phone from email notifications (and admin) under billing address
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'remove_billing_phone_from_formatted_billing_address', 100, 2 );
function remove_billing_phone_from_formatted_billing_address( $billing_address, $order ) {
    unset($billing_address['phone']);
  
    return $billing_address;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> For billing custom fields, you will replace the hooks:
>
> - `woocommerce_shipping_fields` by `woocommerce_billing_fields`
> - `woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields` by `woocommerce_admin_billing_fields`
> - `woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address` by `woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address`
> - *(don't use the last function)*.

---

**For the front endpoints:**

On order received (thank you), order-pay, and myaccount / order-view, you will have [to override via your active theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) the template [`order/order-details-customer.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.0/templates/order/order-details-customer.php).

You will add inside the html tag `<address>` after line 52 the following:

```
        <?php if ( $shipping_phone = $order->get_meta('_shipping_phone') ) : ?>
            <p class="woocommerce-customer-details--phone"><?php echo esc_html( $shipping_phone ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

---

**On admin side, the shipping phone is displayed and editable:**

[image]

---

On order-view, order-received and email notifications, the shipping phone is displayed at the end of the shipping address section:

[image]

Comment: Hi Loic, thanks for your help. I have tested it. Works fine except sphone is not printed in emails

Comment: @ZeGregg I can't test email notifications for the moment… I will come back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: #LoicTheAztec I can only see phone in billing in Woo 4.01. No phone in shipping :(

Comment: Super strange. I checked few client install and in admin order edit there are no phone number. I have only on billing. I checked also in my-account from frontend and no shipping phone. That is why a client asked me the feature :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212878/discussion-between-greg-and-loictheaztec).

Comment: I can confirm that shipping phone is not art of latest WC core. Your code works fine except that email in not printed in email send to both customer and admin

Comment: @Greg the emails work again fine on my hosting for my test server, so I will be able to make tests… I will come back to you once done…

Comment: print_r($shipping_address) is well returning shipping address array including new shipping phone but the original shipping address is not formatted ![See screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/wCsSUr2)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec For me in the backend, the shipping phone label is above the phone label. Just after copy pasting your code. I see a lot of 'phone', shouldn't they be 'shipping_phone'? And why does the meta have an underscore (_shipping_phone)?

Comment: This code works perfectly on woocommerce storefront theme, as asker wanted… Now The billing and shipping meta data are saved in the order with a meta_key that always starts with an underscore… This data is also saved as user meta data with a meta_key without starting with an underscore. this is how woocommerce works… So to get custom billing meta data from the order, requires a meta_key like "_billing_custom" (starting with an underscore).