# Shipping phone/shipping email sent to the new order email WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I managed to set up 2 extra fields (phone and email )in the "shipping details" following the [WooCommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

This works as intended backend, however, I'd like it to also be added to the order email (both to the customer and to me) under the "Shipping adress" part of the email. I could use some guidance in how to make it show there as well.

Comment: For shipping phone, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61522677/woocommerce-editable-custom-checkout-field-and-in-get-formatted-shipping-address/61524676#61524676, so it will be similar for shipping email.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yes thank you! That seems to do exactly what I want. Do I just add the email meta under each section to get email as well?